# Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d0f3ff0)

Tags: ios, swift

Estoy desarrollando una app (en XCode Version 11.2 y Swift 4.2) en la que relleno una **LinkedList** y tras trabajar con ella, al eliminar los elementos que la componen se produce el error **Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16d0f3ff0)**. Se produce el error incluso sin trabajar con los elementos de la lista, simplemente con añadirlos e intentar eliminarlos ya se produce el error. Las pruebas las estoy haciendo con un iPhone con versión de IOS 11.4.1

La implementación de la LinkedList es la siguiente:

```
import Foundation

public class Node<T> {

    var value: T
    var next: Node<T>?
    weak var previous: Node<T>?

    init(value: T) {
        self.value = value
    } // init
} // Node

public class LinkedList<T> {

    private var head: Node<T>?

    private var tail: Node<T>?

    public private(set) var count: Int = 0

    public init() { } // init

    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        return  self.head == nil
    } // isEmpty

    public var first: Node<T>? {
        return  self.head
    } // first

    public var last: Node<T>? {
        return  self.tail
    } // last

    public func nodeAt(index: Int) -> Node<T>? {
        if index >= 0 {
            var node =  self.head
            var i = index
            while node != nil {
                if i == 0 {
                    return node
                } // if

                i -= 1
                node = node!.next
            } // while
        } // if

        return nil
    } // nodeAt

    public func removeAll() {
        self.head = nil
        self.tail = nil

        self.count = 0
    } // removeAll

    public func remove(node: Node<T>?) -> String {
        if isEmpty {
            return String("ERROR: Empty list, nothing to remove.")
        } // if

        guard node != nil else {
           return String("ERROR: Invalid node, nothing to remove.")
        } // guard

        let prev = node?.previous
        let next = node?.next

        if next != nil && prev == nil {
            self.head = next
            next?.previous = nil
        } else if next != nil && prev != nil {
            prev?.next = next
            next?.previous = prev
        } else if next == nil && prev != nil {
             self.tail = prev
            prev?.next = nil
        } // if
        node?.previous = nil
        node?.next = nil

        self.count -= 1
        return String("Successfully removed node: \(node!.value)")
    } // remove

    func enqueue(value: T) {
        let newNode = Node(value: value)

        if let tailNode =  self.tail {
               newNode.previous = tailNode
               tailNode.next = newNode
        } else {
                self.head = newNode
        } // else
        self.tail = newNode
        self.count += 1
    }

    func enqueue_first(value: T) {
        let newNode = Node(value: value)

        if let headNode =  self.head {
               newNode.next = headNode
               headNode.previous = newNode
        } else {
                self.head = newNode
        } // else
         self.count += 1
    }

    func dequeue() -> T? {
        let element =  self.head?.value
        self.head =  self.head?.next
        self.count -= 1

        return element
    }

} // LinkedList
```

Los nodos de la misma son del tipo HexRecord:

```
public class HexRecord
{
    private var length: Int = 0
    private var address: Int64 = 0
    private var type: Int32 = 0
    private var data = [UInt8] ()
    private var checksum: UInt8 = 0

    init()
    {

    }

    public func getAddress() -> Int64 {
        return address;
    }

    public func getType() -> Int32 {
        return type;
    }

    public func getData() -> [UInt8] {
        return data;
    }

    public func getLength() -> Int {
        return length;
    }

    public func getChecksum() -> UInt8 {
        return checksum;
    }


    public func setAddress(address: Int64) {
        self.address = address;
    }

    public func setData(data: [UInt8]) {
        self.data = data;
    }

    public func setLength(length: Int) {
        self.length = length;
    }

    public func setType(type: Int32) {
        self.type = type;
    }

    public func setChecksum(checksum: UInt8) {
        self.checksum = checksum;
    }
}
```

Se utiliza de la siguiente forma:

```
func tratar_registros() {

    var records = LinkedList<HexRecord>();

    ....

    let data_line: HexRecord? = try parseRecord(line: line)  // parseRecord convierte de un String al objeto HexRecord
    if (data_line != nil)
    {
        records.enqueue(value: data_line!)
    }
    ....

    records.removeAll();        //Aqui da el error

} // Aqui da el error si no está la linea records.removeAll();
```

Alguna idea de qué puede estar pasando?

Gracias

Comment: En dónde declaras la variable **line** que envías como parámetro. El método **parseRecord** utilizas alguna librería Pod?

Comment: Es cierto, no se ve la definición. Es un String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se solucionó cambiando el método removeAll de la LinkedList, por lo siguiente:

```
public func removeAll() {
    while head != nil {
        removeTail()
    }
} 


public func removeTail() {
    guard let tail = tail else {return}
    if let prev = tail.previous {
        prev.next = nil
        self.tail = prev
    } else {
        self.head = nil
        self.tail = nil
    }
    count -= 1


    if count < 0 { count = 0}
}
```

Comment: Recuerda de marcarte la respuesta como la correcta aunque seas tu mismo y ya de paso mirate el siguiente enlace [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)